# How to setup demo page in GitHub showing my project's index.html?

Tags: github

I have setup my repository on GitHub and would like to create a demo page on GitHub itself.
How do I setup a demo page showing my project's `index.html` ? I googled but dont seem to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your GitHub project, you can mention in your README a link to an associated **[GitHub Page](http://pages.github.com/)**.
(you can also [create it manually](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually))

That will translate, in your repo in a separate `gh-pages` branch, in which you can add your web pages.

But you cannot directly "include" or "import" that project web page directly in your main GitHub page (which only reflects your `README.md` file)

---

Since you already have a [project page](http://rdesai03.github.io/stopwatch_dojo/), you can embed your [jsfidle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/P7b9S/76/embedded/result/) following:
"[Embedding the fiddle](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/embedding.html)"

> Embedding is provided to show the fiddle with running result on any other page.

```
URL: http://{url_of_the_fiddle}/embedded/[{tabs}/[{style}]]/

<iframe
  style="width: 100%; height: 300px"
  src="http://jsfiddle.net/zalun/NmudS/embedded/">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Not sure if you got my question correctly. I do not want to create a project page. I already have it here: http://rdesai03.github.io/stopwatch_dojo/ I want to show a working demo like it shows in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/P7b9S/76/embedded/result/

Comment: @RahulDesai I understand. Hence the last sentence of my answer. Your GitHub page only reflect `README.md`. You can show your working demo on your project page.

Comment: How do I show working demo on the project page? Are you refering to GitHub page and project page as two different pages? Or, are they the same as I provided in the link above?

Comment: @RahulDesai 2 different pages: you should be able to show what you want at http://rdesai03.github.io/stopwatch_dojo/, not at https://github.com/rdesai03/stopwatch_dojo/

Comment: @RahulDesai I have edited my answer to include a link explaining how to embed your demo in an html page (like your project page)

Comment: So thats about embedding jsFiddle into the project page. I am sure there is a way to show the `index.html` in GitHub directly. I dont have a sample link ready right now but I have seen people doing that. (Or they might have embedded as well, I dont know. :)

Comment: @RahulDesai what do you mean by "in GitHub directly"? Do you mean in what is displayed in https://github.com/rdesai03/stopwatch_dojo/?

Comment: I mean, without embedding (using my code in GitHub directly). Is it possible?

Comment: @RahulDesai I am still not sure about what you mean with "in GitHub directly": do you have the url of the exact page "in GitHub" you want to modify in order to see your demo?

Comment: I want to ask you if there is any other option other than embedding the fiddle to show the demo? Also, if I decide to embed, is it possible to embed the `iframe` code in `markdown`  ?

Comment: @RahulDesai not that I know of.

Comment: @RahulDesai No: Markdown doesn't support any kind of embedding. That is what I am telling in my answer. You can embed in a project page (http://rdesai03.github.io/stopwatch_dojo/), not in a GitHub page (https://github.com/rdesai03/stopwatch_dojo/)

Comment: Twitter was able to achieve a demo on GitHub (http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) so why cant I? :)

Comment: @RahulDesai it is best to look at the source code of that demo page: it is custom made to include what they need.